# jQuery autocomplete dynamic ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I'm trying to build a search input with the autocomplete feature. However, the suggestions depend on the input and are not static - which means that I have to retrieve the list every time the user types into the field. The suggestions are based on Google autosuggest: "http://google.com/complete/search?q=TERM&output=toolbar".

I'm currently using http://easyautocomplete.com.

This is my code:

```
        var array = [];
        var options = {
            data: array
        };

        $("#basics").easyAutocomplete(options);

        $("#basics").on("keyup",function() {
            var keyword = $(this).val();
            array = [];
            updateSuggestions(keyword);
        });


        function updateSuggestions(keyword) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{{ path('suggestKeywords') }}",
                data: {keyword:keyword},
                success: function(res){
                    var res = JSON.parse(res);

                    for(var i in res)
                    {
                        var suggestion = res[i][0];
                        array.push(suggestion);
                        console.log(suggestion);
                    }

                }
            });

            var options = {
                data: array
            };
            $("#basics").easyAutocomplete(options);

        }
```

I know this is not a very good way to do this - so do you have any suggestions as to how to do it?

Comment: Refer this http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete functionality</title>
  <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <!-- Javascript -->
  <script>
    $(function() {
      var availableTutorials = [
        "ActionScript",
        "Boostrap",
        "C",
        "C++",
      ];
      $("#automplete-1").autocomplete({
        source: availableTutorials
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- HTML -->
  <div class="ui-widget">
    <p>Type "a" or "s"</p>
    <label for="automplete-1">Tags:</label>
    <input id="automplete-1">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```